# How to edit a webform block (not the webform itself)

Tags: blocks, captcha

I have one webform block I would like to edit. I know I can use hook_form_alter, the problem is that any changes I make using it are affecting the actual webform plus the block.

How can change stuff just on the webform block? It's just a captcha component I want to disable, thanks.

Comment: If you're wanting to disable the captcha, that part is in the form, so you need to modify the form. You do want to modify the webform but only when it appears in a block. Have you tried using hook_form_alter to see if there is any data attached to either the $form or $form_state array which you can test to see if this webform is currently being output by a block as opposed to the page view?

Comment: I have tried but there doesn't seem to be anything that gives a hint that it's a block and not a node.

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way is to create a separate form for that block (a copy of what you have now, but dedicated to that block), and disable Captcha for that form name

Comment: I like this suggestion, let me give it a try but as last option. Would be great to catch everything that happens on one form for a certain purpose in one place but thanks, it's a great workaround.

Comment: I know what you mean... I think otherwise you would need to customise Captcha to allow for an exception on that particular block, or create a custom module to handle it. One way to think about it though is that the block version could be a mini version of the full form... semantics I realise, but these things help me sleep at night sometimes :)